# Apache rewrite rule, too many redirects error

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I am trying to implement a rewrite rule that I need someone's help to comple..

Here is my requirement..

```
HTTPS://{domain}/contextPath/browse      //should transformed to
HTTPS://{domain}/contextPath?dl=browse
```

Another sample..

```
HTTPS://{domain}/contextPath/login      //should transformed to
HTTPS://{domain}/contextPath?dl=login
```

When I tried with this rule I am getting too many redirects error..

```
RewriteRule ^/contextPath/(*) ^/contextPath?dl=$1 [R,L]
```

Can you please help me with this

`- [03/Mar/2016:20:40:38 -0600] "GET /contextPath/loginall HTTP/1.1" 404 983 [Thu Mar 03 20:40:38.809774 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 20144:tid 47425062725952] mod_rewrite.c(468): [rid#1ab7ae90/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /contextPath/loginall [Thu Mar 03 20:40:38.809805 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 20144:tid 47425062725952] mod_rewrite.c(468): [rid#1ab7ae90/initial] rewrite '/contextPath/loginall' -> '/contextPath?dl=loginall' [Thu Mar 03 20:40:38.809821 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 20144:tid 47425062725952] mod_rewrite.c(468): [rid#1ab7ae90/initial] local path result: /contextPath [Thu Mar 03 20:40:38.809877 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 20144:tid 47425062725952] mod_rewrite.c(468): [rid#1ab7ae90/initial] prefixed with document_root to /apps/install/apache/httpd/htdocs_browser/contextPath [Thu Mar 03 20:40:38.809891 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 20144:tid 47425062725952] mod_rewrite.c(468): [rid#1ab7ae90/initial] go-ahead with /apps/install/apache/httpd/htdocs_browser/contextPath [OK] [03/Mar/2016:20:40:38 -0600] 172.17.130.161 TLSv1.2 RC4-SHA "GET /contextPath/loginall HTTP/1.1" 983`

Comment: Why is the **^** in target path?

Comment: For the domain name purpose, is it not required.

Comment: Is this `RewriteRule` directive in your .htaccess file? (Actually, I see that the `.htaccess` tag has been added to the question later, but your `RewriteRule` pattern would not match in .htaccess.)

Comment: No I don't have anything related in .htaccess & not sure how that tag added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

> `RewriteRule ^/contextPath/(*) ^/contextPath?dl=$1 [R,L]`

There seems to be a number of issues with this directive:

- The pattern `(*)` is not valid, it should be `(.*)`
- The `^` character at the start of the substitution does not make sense. The `^` (caret) is a start of string anchor in a regex. The substitution string is not a regex. So, unless you have a literal `^` in your URL, this should be omitted.
- This should be an *internal rewrite*, not an *external redirect* (`R` flag). Presumably you don't want to expose your `/contextPath?dl=` URLs to the user?

Try something like the following in your Apache config:

```
# Internally rewrite the request providing the "dl" param is not already present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !dl=
RewriteRule ^/contextPath/(.+) contextPath?dl=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It didn't work :( I have updated my query section with trace logs. Can you please suggest

Comment: "trace logs"? What do you mean by "didn't work"? "too many redirects still"?

Comment: Do I need to have directive created, I hope not, the request should go tomcat

Comment: A 404 could suggest that these rules/directives are not being processed. Try adding the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule` - does it redirect? What does it redirect to? What do you mean by "Do I need to have directive created"? All the instructions above are called _directives_.